# UIPasteboard Policies for deleting data

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

1. What does UIPasteboard do when it is "full"? Does it delete the oldest files first?
2. Is there any limit to the total size in MB for UIPasteboard?

My use case: Storing Video Files as NSData in pasteboard. Each is a 30 second Video Advertising clip that will be used across apps. Naturally, I am wondering how many I am allowed to store, when will they be deleted if I don't age/delete them myself.

Furthermore, I have noticed that the data in pasteboard does not get deleted even when the app is deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: limit of 8 mb is there

Comment: but you can store your data in files and put their url in the pastboard